# Check if column contains a value T-SQL before insert into it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;
    INSERT INTO [TaskNotification] (TaskId, EmpKey)
        SELECT 
            TaskId, E.EmpKey
        FROM 
            @TaskNotificationTableType TNT
        INNER JOIN 
            Employee E ON E.EmpGuid = TNT.EmpGuid;
COMMIT TRAN
```

I want to know how can I check if my column `E.EmpKey` value exists before insert value for example

```
IF (E.EmpKey EXISTS) 
    // DO NOTHING
ELSE
    INSERT INTO [TaskNotification] (TaskId, EmpKey)
        SELECT 
            TaskId, E.EmpKey
        FROM 
            @TaskNotificationTableType TNT
        INNER JOIN 
            Employee E ON E.EmpGuid = TNT.EmpGuid;
```

How can I achieve it? Regards

Comment: How about using a WHERE clause in the insert statement (`WHERE E.EmpKey IS NOT NULL`)?

Comment: To add to WolfgangK's comment: Use [`@@RowCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or an [`output` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to check whether anything was inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that `EmpKey` doesn't have to be NULL on `Employee` then filtering on the `WHERE` will suffice.

```
INSERT INTO [TaskNotification] (TaskId, EmpKey)
SELECT 
    TaskId, E.EmpKey
FROM 
    @TaskNotificationTableType TNT
INNER JOIN 
    Employee E ON E.EmpGuid = TNT.EmpGuid
WHERE
    E.EmpKey IS NOT NULL;
```

If you mean that you don't want to insert a record in `TaskNotification` if it already exists then use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

```
INSERT INTO [TaskNotification] (TaskId, EmpKey)
SELECT 
    TaskId, E.EmpKey
FROM 
    @TaskNotificationTableType TNT
INNER JOIN 
    Employee E ON E.EmpGuid = TNT.EmpGuid
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'not in TaskNotification yet' FROM [TaskNotification] T
                WHERE T.EmpKey = E.EmpKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

`@@rowcount` Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;
SELECT E.EmpKey
FROM @TaskNotificationTableType TNT;

IF @@rowcount > 0 
  INSERT INTO [TaskNotification] (TaskId, EmpKey)
        SELECT 
            TaskId, E.EmpKey
        FROM 
            @TaskNotificationTableType TNT
        INNER JOIN 
            Employee E ON E.EmpGuid = TNT.EmpGuid;
commit tran
```